# Airflow - colored logging

Tags: python, airflow

Is there any way to implement color highlights for the logs in Airflow UI (stdout logs)?
I want to mark some logs, for example Exceptions messages in red and Success messages in green.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the standard config available in Airflow. You'd have to contribute your own code to do this.